# Like a photo on behalf of facebook app user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am making an app where I am posting a photo as a result. I want to like the photo on behalf of the app user, without the user actually clicking the like link on the photo.
My aim behind this is that the like will get posted on the user's profile and get noticed by their friends.
Is this possible?

I am using php sdk but can work with JS sdk as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [facebook photo api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) :

> You can like a photo by issuing a HTTP POST request to PHOTO_ID/likes connection with the publish_stream permission. No parameters necessary.

All you have to do is retrieve an access token for the page.  You can learn how to do that [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) under the section **App Login**

Comment: I dont have any access token. I am using the following url for permissions:

    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
           . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" .  urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope="."user_photos,publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access";

  
Can you please help me with a piece of code? how to do the post request and will the api call consist of user id as well?

Comment: you can get your pages access token by making a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=client_credentials`

Comment: @SandiipPatil, you'll have to do some research on your own. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is the facebook documentation on authentication.  You use the access token for all your requests to facebook.   The access token proves to facebook your identity.